# Trying to set a default asset folder using Craft tags

Tags: assets, field, tags

I'm trying to set a default asset folder for a field, as per the Craft docs on [Dynamic Subfolder Paths](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths).

I'm trying to set the asset path for each blog article to be `/our-journal/{date}/{slug}`, where date is the creation date of the article, falling back to today's date otherwise.

```
/our-journal/{ entry.dateCreated|date('Y-m') ?: now|dateCreated('Y-m') }/{ slug }
```

I'm getting an internal server error:

> Could not resolve the subpath “our-journal/{ entry.dateCreated|date('Y-m') ?: now|dateCreated('Y-m') }/{ slug }”.

I've tried using both single and double braces around the variables, as the docs are a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Is Asset field inside of a Matrix field?

Comment: I've got the default path on two fields - one on the entry and one in a matrix field on the same entry type. As far as I can see, it's the field directly on the entry that is causing the issue (probably both are, but that one is hitting validation first).

Comment: Thanks for your help @BradBell, I found a stupid typo. Also found something interesting about how Craft handles asset uploads on unsaved entries - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had a stupid typo in my path, where instead of the `date` filter, I'd typed `dateCreated`:

```
/our-journal/{ entry.dateCreated|date('Y-m') ?: now|dateCreated('Y-m') }/{ slug }
```

Should be:

```
/our-journal/{ entry.dateCreated|date('Y-m') ?: now|date('Y-m') }/{ slug }
```

Which, with what I learnt about fallbacks (see below), can be shortened to:

```
/our-journal/{ entry.dateCreated|date('Y-m') }/{ slug }
```

And if you're doing this within a matrix field, the entry is referred to by `owner` - so you'd need:

```
/our-journal/{ owner.dateCreated|date('Y-m') }/{ owner.slug }/
```

**Fallbacks**

I also found that I didn't need to provide fallbacks for entry tags - I'd thought that I'd need to provide a fallback for when a new entry hasn't yet been saved (to stop it falling over on e.g. `dateCreated`).

It appears that Craft is clever enough to hold the image in some temporary store, then move it into the intended folder when the article is first saved.